# Field references in Java bytecode

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I've found something in the Java bytecode spec I don't understand.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class FilterOutputStream {
  protected OutputStream out;
}

class PrintStream extends FilterOutputStream {
  public void write(...) {
    out.write(...);
  }
}
```

Looking at the bytecode for PrintStream with javap, I see that reading the `out` field is done like this:

```
getfield #21
```

Reference #21 is, as expected, a Field reference, containing the class, name and descriptor of the field. However, it looks like this:

```
const #21 = Field #30.#204; //  java/io/PrintStream.out:Ljava/io/OutputStream;
```

This is really puzzling, because that says that the `out` field is a member of PrintStream. That's not true; it's a member of FilterOutputStream, and that's the class I'd expect to see in the field reference above. The JVM spec is pretty woolly, but appears to back me up:

> The value of the class_index item must be a valid index into the constant_pool table.
>   The constant_pool entry at that index must be a CONSTANT_Class_info (§4.4.1) structure
>   representing a class or interface type that has the field or method as a member.

(From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.2.)

This is a problem for me, because I look at the field reference, load the class, and then fail to find the field. On the other hand, Java compilers do work, so it's obviously my understanding that's wrong...

Can someone clarify this for me? Am I supposed to load the class, look for the field reference, and if it's not found start working up the class hierarchy until I find it?

Pointers into the spec to where it describes the correct behaviour for doing this would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the part of the JVM spec where it talks about field lookup. If the field doesn't exist in the current class, it starts searching superclasses and interfaces.

```
5.4.3.2 Field Resolution
To resolve an unresolved symbolic reference from D to a field in a class or interface
C, the symbolic reference to C given by the field reference must first be resolved
(§5.4.3.1). Therefore, any exception that can be thrown as a result of failure of
resolution of a class or interface reference can be thrown as a result of field
resolution. If the reference to C can be successfully resolved, an exception relating
to the failure of resolution of the field reference itself can be thrown.
When resolving a field reference, field resolution first attempts to look up the
referenced field in C and its superclasses:
1. If C declares a field with the name and descriptor specified by the field
reference, field lookup succeeds. The declared field is the result of the field
lookup.
2. Otherwise, field lookup is applied recursively to the direct superinterfaces of
the specified class or interface C.
3. Otherwise, if C has a superclass S, field lookup is applied recursively to S.
4. Otherwise, field lookup fails.
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. (This has actually _changed_ since the last time I did any detailed work with bytecode. Fields on interfaces? That's just wrong...)